# News about our launch as a full SE site

Tags: discussion

Recently I noticed that the [TeX site](http://tex.stackexchange.com) launched, even though it was behind us in the [queue](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress) to graduate to full site-dom.  I did some digging around and found this excellent Q&A on the [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) [meta](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com) and thought I would share:

- [Beta progress, importance of reputation, and voting](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/263)

If what the poster says is accurate, we're at least a couple of weeks out from launch.

Answer (score 3):

It would be worth stressing the importance of voting - this is the only way to get those high rep voters.

You can vote 30 times a day.

If you use up all your votes in one day you get the [Suffrage](https://diy.stackexchange.com/badges/62/suffrage) badge - one time only.

If you vote 300 times you get the [Civic Duty](https://diy.stackexchange.com/badges/32/civic-duty) badge.

And if you vote on 600+ questions and those votes make up more than 25% of your total votes you get the [Electorate](https://diy.stackexchange.com/badges/44/electorate) badge.

**UPDATE 24th November**

I've just checked the stats page on Area 51 and we're now all "Okay" or "Excellent" so I guess if we stay that way we'll launch fairly soon. Watch out for a post from [Jin](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6/jin) the designer!

Comment: Though having just visited the [Area 51 proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/170/home-improvement) it's the visits/day that appears to be holding us in beta.

Answer (score 3):

Although the rate of questions and answers has remained fairly constant, the rate of visits started increasing sharply around November 1.  My guess is that it means that our Google ranking has increased, so we are steadily getting more traffic from there.  Over time it should lead to more avid users and more questions, but I don't know how quickly.  The rate of new users has not increased to match the increased traffic.

Comment: Visits is good. Over the longer term it will convert into users. We just need to continue to provide good answers.